# Как заставить NodeJS искать модули не только в «node_modules»?

Tags: node.js

Допустим есть проект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытаюсь написать скрипт `init.bat` который будет запускать сервер.
При запуске из bat-файла или из командной строки, я получаю ошибку `cannot find module 'core/base/globals'`

Дело в том, что в файле `server.js` есть строка `require('core/base/globals');` которая подключает данный файл.

Если я напишу так: `require('../core/base/globals')` - то все будет работать. 
Но суть в том, что при такой записи: `require('core/base/globals');` сервер подымается если запускать его через WebStorm, а через cmd - нет. Выполняю команду из корня проекта в cmd: `set NODE_PATH="." && set NODE_ENV="development" && node --use_strict bin/server` и получаю ошибку `Error: Cannot find module 'core/base/globals'`

Я хочу понять, как запускает проект WebStorm чтобы не переделывать все записи (их оч много) с require на такие: `../../../../../myFile`. А все сложить в node_modules у меня нет возможности, т.к. не позволяет структура приложения, и переделывать ее крайне не желательно.

Кто сталкивался с подобными вещами? Есть идеи?

Comment: *а через cmd - нет* -- а попробуйте из корня проекта запустить `bin\init.bat`, прямо со слэшом :)

Comment: @Кнопкатык не работает, не все так просто!

Comment: @Кнопкатык, пробовал еще так из cmd: `node --use_strict  C:\Users\sanu0074\myapp\bin\server` - результат тот-же

Comment: @Кнопкатык из bin, корня проекта, и просто сразу после запуска cmd.exe

Comment: Да, похоже, что рабочую директорию он игнорирует. Вообще на эту тему есть [целый обзор разных способов](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520). Предполагаю, что вебшторм использует решение с `NODE_PATH`, но у меня нету этой IDE и я не хочу её ставить. Можете проверить и заняться переводом :)

Comment: Я использую bash скрипт для запуска nodejs аппликации и таких проблем нет. Насколько я знаю, нода ищет файлы относительно директории, в которой находится главный файл (в Вашем случае server). Думаю если переместить этот файл в рут директорию, то все должно быть в порядке

Comment: @Кнопкатык, спасибо, нашел ответ в статье по вашей ссылке: `(On Windows this command will not work if you put a space in between the path and the &&. Crazy shit.)` Остается проблема с батником, такая запись как в статье `@echo off 
cmd.exe /C "set NODE_PATH=.&& set NODE_ENV=development&& node --use_strict  ../bin/server"` выдает ошибку `cannot find module 'core/base/globals'`. Наверняка чего-то не хватает

Comment: Из какой папки запускаете на этот раз?

Comment: @Кнопкатык, сделал так: `cmd.exe /C "cd ../ && set NODE_PATH=.&& set NODE_ENV=development&& node --use_strict bin/n24server"` - работает. С точки зрения написания bat файлов это нормальный вариант? (p.s. как то смотрится убого)

Comment: Ну, инспекция кода это уже совсем другая тема. Мне кажется странным использование там `cmd.exe` при том, что батники и так запускаются в нём же. Склеивать всё в одну строчку, когда есть контекст батника, тоже странно, можно задать переменные среды через `set` (или `setlocal`, не уверен, мало работал с батниками) на отдельных строчках. Всё цивильно.

Comment: @Кнопкатык, спасибо, переписал так:` @echo off
cd ../
set NODE_PATH=.
set NODE_ENV=development
node --use_strict bin/server`

Answer (score 1):

```
set NODE_PATH=".;core/..;" && node bin/server
```